# g++ std::set cannot find operator< defined for class

Tags: c++, gcc, stl, operator-overloading

When trying to compile the following code (simplified from original):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

namespace OrbitSets {
    class rational;
}

bool operator<(OrbitSets::rational a, OrbitSets::rational b);

namespace OrbitSets {

    // Class definition
    class rational {
    private:
        long long numerator;
        long long denominator;
    public:
        rational() {
            numerator = 0;
            denominator = 1;
        }
        rational(int a) {
            numerator = a;
            denominator = 1;
        }

        friend bool ::operator<(rational a, rational b);
    };
}

// Ordering operations
inline bool operator<(OrbitSets::rational a, OrbitSets::rational b) {
    return a.numerator * b.denominator < b.numerator * a.denominator;
}

int main() {
    const OrbitSets::rational a = 5;
    const OrbitSets::rational b = 3;

    std::set<OrbitSets::rational> c;
    c.insert(a);

    if (a < b) return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

gcc complains on the c.insert line that it cannot find operator< for the OrbitSets::rational class, giving the following error:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_function.h:387:20: error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const OrbitSets::rational’ and ‘const OrbitSets::rational’)
       { return __x < __y; }
```

However, when commenting away the c.insert(a) line, the code compiles correctly, even though two lines later a similar comparison is done, with the same type of arguments.

I'm using g++ to compile this, why isn't it able to find the aformentioned operator for use in the less<..> template class, but is able to find it for use 2 lines later?

Comment: Put the operator in the same namespace as `rational`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `set::insert` tries to evaluate the expression `__x < __y` to compare your objects, the compiler does an [Argument-Dependent Lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

The first step in this is [Unqualified Name Lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup).  Since the expression is used inside `namespace std`, this lookup finds several functions `std::operator<` (as you can see in the long compiler error output), and stops there.

Then the compiler figures out what the "associated namespaces and classes" are for the function call.  Since both arguments have the same class type, the only associated class is `OrbitSets::rational` and the only associated namespace is `OrbitSets`.

Since your `operator<` is in the global namespace, it is not found by the associated namespace lookup.

What I don't understand yet is why rule [basic.argdep.lookup]/4.2 doesn't apply:

> - Any namespace-scope friend functions or friend function templates declared in associated classes are visible within their respective namespaces even if they are not visible during an ordinary lookup.

Seems to me you do have a namespace-scope friend function which is declared in an associated class, even though it's not the first declaration.  But both g++ and clang++ give the same error, and at least one of them is usually right....

Your `(a < b)` expression is not in a scope containing any other `operator<`, so the set of `::operator<` overloads in the global namespace, including the one you meant, is found in that case.

In any case, you can fix this by moving your `operator<` inside `namespace
OrbitSets`.

Comment: Since the `operatror <` is defined in the global scope isn't it not a *namespace-scope friend function*?

Comment: [basic.scope.namespace]/3 "The outermost declarative region of a translation unit is also a namespace, called the _global namespace_.  A name declared in the global namespace has _global namespace scope_ (also called _global scope_)."